# Difference between two lists to create a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset, like this `mushrooms <- read.csv("mushrooms.csv")` and now I already have a `mushrooms.training_set` which is 1/3 of the whole dataset. For both variables, `typeof()` returns `list`.

Now, I want to select the rows in the original dataset `mushrooms`, that are not in the `mushrooms.training_set`. How would I do this? I have tried the following:

- `mushrooms[c(!mushrooms.training_set),]` but this returns something in the order of 64K rows.
- `mushrooms[!mushrooms.training_set,]`
- `mushrooms[!duplicated(mushrooms.training_set)]`

Who helps me out?

Comment: `typeof()` is of very limited use because of how general it is. `class()` or especially `str()` tell you much more useful information. Almost certainly your data is a `data.frame`, which is much more useful information than saying it's a `list`. Data frames are a very special kind of list.

Comment: can you please show us something like `str(mushrooms)`, `str(mushrooms.training_set)` ?

Comment: You are right, @Gregor, they are both data.frames

Comment: I've been seeing `typeof()` in newbie questions more frequently lately. Is there some blog post or course telling people to use `typeof`? Something I could comment on or send an email to the author to tell them to stop giving bad advice?

Comment: I'm not sure where I got it from, I'll retrace my steps later. And I'll let you know :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693908/get-type-of-all-variables
This question for example.

Comment: I suggest rather than proceed like this you have look at the `caret` package which contains a framework for splitting data into training and test sets. Have a look at this example for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575580/1527403

Comment: @jbehrens94 yes, but that's an old question and doesn't seem like the thing too many people would stumble on. I feel like I've seen 4-5 questions using `typeof` in the last few months, and maybe 1 in the previous 3 years.

Comment: It's the one I actually found when typing 'R type of variable', this was the first hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From where you are in the question, you can use `dplyr::setdiff`:

```
library(dplyr)
mushroooms.test = setdiff(mushrooms, mushrooms.training_set)
```

But most of the time it's easier to create the test set using at the same time as the training set. Lots of examples here at [How to split data into training and test sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17200114/903061)

Comment: huh.  Does `setdiff` work on an entire data frame?

Comment: I just tried this code, but I end up with the same dataset as `mushrooms`?

Comment: Oops, no it doesn't. Really thought it did.

Comment: Ah, `dplyr::setdiff` does work on entire data frames.

Comment: +1 for the last two sentences, which answer the OP's underlying problem. However, the OP's literal question (difference between two data.frames) is [clearly a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join) and a common one at that

Comment: I actually am doing that, but I just think I wanted to outsmart myself unknowingly, haha.