# Loop over objects in global environment

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, environment-variables, global-variables

I'm pretty new to R and trying to write a loop or a concise code for a simple task: checking the class of all the current objects in my Global Environment in R.

```
class(mydata)
#[1] "data.frame"
class(mylist)
#[1] "list"
class(mymatrix)
#[1] "matrix"
...
```

The following code worked, but what if I have many objects and I don't want to type all the names.

```
dflist <- list(mydata, mylist, mymatrix)
lapply(dflist,class)
```

I tried the following methods, none of them worked.

```
 #1
for (i in ls()){
  class(i)
}

 #2
for (i in ls()){
  lapply(i,class)
}
```

any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something you should be doing if you are new to R. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JackBrookes I want to practice writing loops in R. For this particular example, I want to get classes for all the data frames in my current environment.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693908/get-type-of-all-variables

Comment: @zx8754 thank you! wish I saw that post earlier. eapply(.GlobalEnv,class) does the trick for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `mget` which returns "a named list of objects". The function's first argument should be a character vector of object names, which is what `ls()` returns.

```
lapply(mget(ls()), class)
#$mydata
#[1] "data.frame"
# 
#$mylist
#[1] "list"
#
#$mymatrix
#[1] "matrix"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `eapply`:

```
eapply(.GlobalEnv, class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sapply`:

```
sapply(ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) any(class(get(x)) %in% c("data.frame", "matrix", "list")))], function(x) class(get(x)))
```

Comment: thanks. but it returns all classes of the objects (vectors) in Values but not the objects (data frames, matrixes, lists) in the Data section in my environment.

Comment: Thanks!!! @markus 's code is shorter (more optimized).

Comment: @markus code applies to all objects, though. I adjusted the code so that vectors can be excluded.

Comment: You're right. Thanks! Somehow I feel like it can still be optimized.